# Bind ngModel value across components

Tags: angularjs, angular

Say you have *about.component.ts* with the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'about-section',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="First Name">
    <p>{{name || 'user'}}</p>
  ` 
})

export class AboutComponent {

}
```

Then you have *notes.component.ts*:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'notes-section',
  template: `
    <p>{{name || 'user'}}</p>
  ` 
})

export class NotesComponent {

}
```

Both files are components of *app.component.ts*:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { NotesComponent } from './notes.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <about-section></about-section>
  <notes-section></notes-section>
  `,
  directives: [AboutComponent, NotesComponent]
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

My question is, how would you bind the ngModel 'name' property from *about.component.ts* to *notes.component.ts* so whenever you write your name, the change is reflected both in the notes component and the about component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is using `EventEmitter`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'about-section',
  template: `
    <input [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="name = $event; modelChanged.emit($event)">
    <p>{{name || 'user'}}</p>
  ` 
})
export class AboutComponent {
  @Output() modelChanged = new EventEmitter();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'notes-section',
  template: `<p>{{name || 'user'}}</p>` 
})
export class NotesComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <about-section (modelChanged)="notes.name = $event"></about-section>
   <notes-section #notes></notes-section>`,
  directives: [AboutComponent, NotesComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Check [**demo plunker here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fsyl8CvF5dnKs6jK5jYH?p=preview)

Firstly i extracted banana in a box `[(ngModel)]="name"` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way-binding-with-ngmodel) to emit `EventEmitter` event from the component containing `ngModel`.

```
<input [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="name = $event; modelChanged.emit($event)">
```

Then i just subscribed to this event in parent component:

```
<about-section (modelChanged)="notes.name = $event"></about-section>
```

but before it i kept reference on other component to be able to change `name` as shown in the above code `notes.name = $event` where `$event` is representing "payload" of the raised event (input value in this case).

```
<notes-section #notes></notes-section>
```

Comment: What if I have one input in the notes section, how would you sync the two inputs?